# How do I swap cells using two Onclick Events in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to swap two cells using two separate click events in javascript. The problem is that the values stored by the first click event is overwritten by the second click event, and the console shows me that the StringAdjacent value stored for the second click event has been overwritten. This is my code:

```
//Listen to a Set of Click Events to Swap Cells
document.getElementById('board').addEventListener("click", function(e){
  click1ID = event.target.id;
  click1Class = event.target.className;
  stringAdjacency1 = click1ID.replace('cell','')
  console.log(stringAdjacency1);
  document.getElementById('board').addEventListener("click", function(e){
    click2ID = event.target.id;
    click2Class = event.target.className;
    stringAdjacency2 = click2ID.replace('cell','')
    console.log(stringAdjacency2);
  });
  console.log(stringAdjacency1, stringAdjacency2);
});

function swapIds(click1ID, click1Class, click2ID, click2Class) {
  //Are cells adjacent? If so, swap Cells
  //Check the winning combinations to see if there's a new match;
  //Swap cells;
});
```

Please help!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a click event listener, which when fired by clicking the first cell causes another click event listener to be added.  So when you click the second cell, it will fire the first event listener (overwriting the value), plus the second listener you added after the first one.

You only need to register a single listener who's function can handle the logic:

Something like this should work (didn't test):

```
var firstCell = null;
document.getElementById('board').addEventListener("click", function(e){
  if(!firstCell) {
    firstCell = e.target;
  } else {
     var secondCell = e.target;
     // do whatever logic you want

     // reset first cell
     firstCell = null;
  }
});
```

This will set `firstCell` to be the first cell clicked, then the second click it will no longer be null, so it will go into the else condition and you can do whatever you want.  Then you'll reset `firstCell` so the entire interaction can be repeated.

Comment: ** Thank you!                   .